# Nested Query with just displaying Row Number

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to display just the rownumber from a select query.

```
CREATE TABLE UserInfo(
UserID INT,
modName varchar(255),
modCode varchar(8),
credits INT,
ClassPW INT,
CONSTRAINT FK_UserInfo FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES LoginTable
);
```

I managed to do this:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UserID) AS rownum ,modcode from userinfo where userID = 1
```

But that displays the rownum and modcode with it. I just want to display the rownum and the only way I can think of doing that is a nested query but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Maybe remove `modcode` from the select list?  Can you add sample data?

Comment: Why to select a row_number only without any further column? I guess your description is incorrect. If you want to get the number of entries, use COUNT.